# 5th digit after decimal actual output is not same as the 5th digit after decimal of the expected output

Tags: c

5th digit after decimal actual output is not same as the 5th digit after decimal of the expected output.

output: 558.29498
expected: 558.29496

```
double findMaxAverage(int* nums, int numsSize, int k){
float maxSum = -2147483648;
float currentSum = 0;

for(int i=0; i < numsSize; i++){
    currentSum += nums[i];
    if(i >= k - 1){
        if(currentSum > maxSum) maxSum = currentSum;
        currentSum -= nums[i - (k - 1)];
    }
}
return maxSum/k;
}
```

I tried doing this-

```
return (double)maxSum/k;
```

Please help me out with this.

Comment: Use `double` all the way instead of using `float` and then casting to `double`.

Comment: Alternatively, you could declare `maxSum` and `currentSum` as `long long` and convert to `double` before the division. I'd also separete the `if(currentSum > maxSum) maxSum = currentSum;` from the `if(i >= k - 1)` check.

Comment: @Bob__ In practice you'll probably be able to get away with that. In theory, `int` and `long long` could be the same size.

Comment: @user3386109 True, if you are thinking of possible overflows, but the OP haven't specified the range of input data (nor if negative values are expected).

Comment: @ AryantKumar What is the code supposed to do if the array has less than `k` elements in it?

Comment: Please see [Is floating point math broken?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/588004/is-floating-point-math-broken)
and [Why Are Floating Point Numbers Inaccurate?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21895756/why-are-floating-point-numbers-inaccurate)

Comment: Side note: Instead of `-2147483648`, I suggest that you use [`-FLT_MAX`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/types/limits).

Comment: @AndreasWenzel Another good choice is `-HUGE_VALF` which is -infinity, if `float` supports it, or `-FLT_MAX`.

Comment: If `k` is large, you'll be losing precision by maintaining `currentSum` orders of magnitude larger than the input values - see Tony Finch's [Incremental calculation of weighted mean and variance](https://fanf2.user.srcf.net/hermes/doc/antiforgery/stats.pdf) for some guidance on numerically-stable techniques for these.

Answer (score 3):

Don't throw away precision by using `float` and then casting it to `double`. Start out using double precision floating point numbers.

```
double findMaxAverage(int* nums, int numsSize, int k) {
    double maxSum = -2147483648;
    double currentSum = 0;

    for (int i = 0; i < numsSize; i++) {
        currentSum += nums[i];

        if (i >= k - 1) {
            if (currentSum > maxSum) 
                maxSum = currentSum;

            currentSum -= nums[i - (k - 1)];
        }
    }

    return maxSum/k;
}
```